# Running Go App Engine apps locally.

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to run an App Engine app locally using the [development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/using-local-server#Go_Running_the_development_web_server), as specified in Google's docs. I'm running into a ton of compilation errors due to the go library packaged in the SDK missing system libraries.

Looking at the [SDK download page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/download), it says:

> Note: The Google App Engine Launcher does not work with Go apps.

So is there no way to launch Go apps running on App Engine locally?

Comment: You can launch them locally using `goapp serve`. Check this video out, goes over the process pretty well: https://www.bigmarker.com/remote-meetup-go/Mini-Workshop-Build-a-Web-App-with-Francesc

Comment: goapp serve returns an error that the `context` library, which is a go system library, is not found. This issue seems to be the Google App Engine SDK bundles it's own version of Go that doesn't include the context library.

Answer (score 1):

The GAE Go SDK contains and uses a modified version of Go 1.6.2., and the [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package was added to the standard lib in Go 1.7. The old API that comes bundled in the SDK uses the `appengine.Context` context.

See related question: [AppEngine/Go: Using a new version of Go with the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638348/appengine-go-using-a-new-version-of-go-with-the-sdk)

Comment: Damn, that sucks, because 1.6.x does not work on macOS Sierra.

Comment: if I have go1.8 on my machine how would I develop for GAE. Would I have to have a virtual machine or something?

Comment: @gideon Not needed, the appengine SDK contains a Go compiler. Just start your project with the SDK, and it monitors the Go source files and recompiles / restarts if something changes. Your installed Go is not used by the SDK. At least this is how it worked back in the old days. I'm not up-to-date on this, things might have changed.

Comment: aha. I see so the gae tools have a whole toolchain around go1.6? I see. Now the docs sort of fit. Thanks so much :)